# How to adjust RST fork travel?

Tags: maintenance, fork, suspension

Today I own a RST Champ fork with 100mm of travel.

After doing some research I found that there are 3 travel options 80mm, 100mm and 120mm.

I also find out that the adjustment is done by adding or removing things called "travel spacers".

I've done a lot of research but I couldn't find where are they inside the fork and how does it look like.

RST YouTube channel doesn't explain this, fork manual doesn't either and I couldn't find nobody even doing this adjust in their forks...

Any guesses?

Comment: Did you email RST with the same question yet?

Comment: @Klaster_1 I didn't do it yet...
I'm going to do it now and I'll update here if they answere.
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: can you help me? i want to do this but i need some details.. i have an rst aerial. is it gonna be way different?/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After ask for help RST support, I received a brief explanation by e-mail.

"Dear Euller,
Regarding CHAMP travel adjustment, it needs to be adjusted to be part #2.
You must first remove the part #2 from the fork."

[image]

I think that is enough to start and open the fork.