Is my Insync Odesa 160 suspension fork serviceable?
My Trek 7200 multitrack came with an Insync Odesa 160 suspension fork. I got the whole thing used, and so some paint is chipping and metal is corroding. It would be nice to take it apart to clean, de-corrode, and spot paint everything. However all of the cheap suspension fork servicing videos I've seen have forks with plastic bolts on both sides of the fork, while this one only has a bolt on one side (see pictures). Does this (or any other aspect of it) indicate that it is not serviceable?
And to preempt: I'm aware that this is an extremely cheap fork that is probably not worth servicing. I want to service it anyways.
Edit: added another picture to address Criggie's comment about front brake cables.





It's not the same fork but this question is pretty pertinent: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76784/how-to-service-a-rst-sofi-fork/87507#87507 . Short answer you can do it but you're likely to encounter stuff that's not really made to be serviced.

Good on you for giving this a go.   Consider shopping around for a replacement fork, and then based on price and availability decide how careful you want to be while tearing into your existing fork.

Asides - that front brake cable looks kinda taut.  Is it a bit short or possibly mis-routed?   Also, you have full mudguards which implies more road/wet rides. Your don't need to get another suspension fork; a rigid with the same brake mounts might be perfectly adequate.

@Criggie I added another picture to show the cable routing. To me it seems like a pretty gentle curve from lever to brake, but let me know if I've done something incorrectly.
To your second comment: is a rigid fork preferable just because the wet/snow will destroy a suspension fork, or because those conditions make a suspension fork unnecessary? In the latter case, there's some pretty gnarly potholes where I'm at, so I'd prefer to soften that at least a little bit with a suspension fork.

@LucasMyers Oh you're american with the front brake on the left hand - that make more sense.   You're right that looks fine, but I'd assumed it was going straight to the right hand lever.

Overall: low-end suspensions forks work surprisingly well the first couple of years so I'm with Criggie on throwing 100 EUR at this. On rigid forks: a replacement rigid fork for a bike that came with a suspension fork is far too expensive to be considered. On servicing: No bolt at the bottom close to axle: probably not serviceable. I would replace the fork and then destructively disassemble this one as a learning experience.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see corrosion on the fork itself. On the cheap promax brake and its mounting bolts, yes (both easily and cheaply replaced, would go for Shimano "trekking" V brake). A bit of rust on the headset parts. Probably worth overhauling and perhaps replacing the headset. For paint issues, just clean surface well and use your choice of fingernail polish to touch up.

Also probably a good idea to do bearing service on the wheel hubs if you haven't considered that. Cheap on parts but takes a bit of learning.

@Armand third picture right below the accordion is the corrosion.
Why do you suggest I service the hubs? Totally good to do that, but is there something visually that indicates they're in need of service?

@Lucas Given the condition of the brake, I'm guessing the wheel hubs have probably never been serviced. I think those are cup and cone loose ball bearing hubs, and water and grit works it's way in in spite of any seals. Just seems likely to me...
